# Is math.stackexchange the place to ask questions about scientific programming algorithms?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am looking for a Java-based library or algorithm for efficiently implementing the second Chebyshev function: $\psi(x) = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\vartheta\left(\sqrt[m]{x}\right)$ .

Is this an appropriate question for math.stackexchange?  Would this be better asked on a different StackExchange web site?  If so, does anyone have recommendations?

Thanks,

-Larry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can ask your questions here.

There is a site more relevant than MSE: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: OTOH, since the function concerned is of the analytic number theory bent, I'm sure OP will get better answers here than in scicomp.

Comment: Thanks!  I posted the question on scicomp.  If I don't get an answer over the next day or so, I'll post the same question on MSE.  Cheers.

Comment: @LarryFreeman : crossposting the same question on different Stack Exchange sites is discouraged. If you do this, you should probably remove the question from scicomp first, or include in both posts a statement that the question has been posted on the other site, along with a link.  If you want opinions on crossposting from people more experienced than me, search meta for "crossposting".

Comment: Thanks, Stefan.  I will read the policy before I post the same question anywhere else.